# Jquery - using .this to select a specific button from a group of buttons

Tags: jquery

I have a group of buttons all with the same class name, and some times there will be necessary to grey out one if there is no URL. I am trying to do so by adding a css class `.not-available` to that specific button. But this also adds the class name to all other buttons. Here is the code:

```
$('a').each(function(index) {
   if( $(this).attr('href') == '' ) {
      $('.button').addClass('not-available')
   }
```

Comment: I am guessing there should be a .this somewhere in the code.

Comment: .button is a class, use $(this).addClass

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your if statement is referencing `$('.button')` which will affect all instances of `.button`, not just those with a blank `href`.  Change your selector to `$(this)` which will only target those matched in your conditon.

```
$('a').each(function(index) {

if( $(this).attr('href') == '' )
{
    $(this).addClass('not-available')
}
```

Comment: Thank you! Works like a charm

Comment: Great. Don't forgot to mark as the answer then @EirikHerjeMonsen.

Answer (score 0):

This will work and I tested...
use "find()" method to achieve this...

```
$('a').each(function(index) {
     if($(this).attr('href') == '') {
        $(this).find(".button").addClass('not-available');
     }
}
```